# Create concave corners in css

Tags: css

**Is it possible to create concave corners like this in css? If yes, how would you do it?**

[image]

Comment: Yes, but you have to use several extra elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a good example of how I would tackle this:

http://jsfiddle.net/x4wLf/

HTML:

```
<div class='concave'>
    <div class='topleftconcave'></div>
    <div class='botleftconcave'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 div.concave {
    background:blue;
    width:150px;
    height:120px;
    position:relative;
}
div.topleftconcave {
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    width:25px;
    height:35px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:500px;
}
div.botleftconcave {
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    width:25px;
    height:35px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    border-top-right-radius:500px;
}
```

Comment: That was quick @Korvin. Well done! This is beautiful and this is exactly what I am after!

Comment: This option creates extra elements. Actually it can be solved without adding any extra elements.

Comment: Technically no it can't. The ::before and ::after method is limited to two concave corners as I mentioned in David Thomas's example, that's why I chose adding elements.

Comment: Maybe there is a little disadvantage with this but I am not sure this is possible to avoid it. If there is an image in the background, we will see the corner in a different color right?

Answer (score 10):

Lea Verou has a [description of how to do this](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/):

> By using radial gradients, you can simulate rounded corners with a
>   negative radius. You can do this without the support of any extra
>   elements. Its a little tricky.
>
> It also falls back to a solid color background if CSS gradients are
>   not supported. It will work on Firefox 3.6, latest Webkit and
>   —hopefully— Opera 11.10 (they announced that gradients support is
>   coming). You could add a `-webkit-gradient()` background too, to make
>   it work in practically all versions of Webkit currently in use, but I
>   warn you: It’s not going to be easy and I personally refuse to spend
>   more than 5 minutes of my time messing with that non-standard thing.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/sCBgk/3/)*** is a live demo of their implementation.

Comment: Wow! This actually allows us to use only one div and to have a background image. This is perfect.

Comment: Thanks @Patt :) , I think this is the better way to do this. This creates less headache than others. Consider giving this a +1.

Comment: Indeed, it does look aliased in Safari. Could you explain this: `don't put the color stops at the exact same position`. Can this code work well in Safari and IE?

Comment: This post is originally from Lea Berrou. Here is the [link](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/). Please, don't forget to give the source.

Comment: @Patt - Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited the answer to provide proper credit to Lea for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather not add extra elements to the HTML, need to style only two corners *and* are able to use generated content instead, I'd suggest:

```
.concave {
    position: relative;
    width: 10em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #00f;
    color: #fff;
}

.concave::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1em;
    left: -1em;
    border: 1em solid #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.concave::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1em;
    left: -1em;
    border: 1em solid #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FPsuW/).

Comment: I was going to go this route, but this unfortunately doesn't allow for all four corners, only two.

Comment: There is that slight problem, yes.

Comment: Thanks @David. This is an awesome code.

Comment: @Patt: you're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! It is, unfortunately, rather limited though. =)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to add four divs at the four corners, each with a positive border radius.

Answer (score 0):

What about the CSS3 border-image property? Great article here:

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

It will mean no support for older browsers such as IE 7-8, but if you can live with that or find a work around this would work well.

I recently done used border-image myself to do this exact thing.